# Report "Errors" in English Language & Usage?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was going through the FAQs in Help Section and came across this question

....

**[Can I support my product on this site?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/product-support)**

> **Types of questions and where to ask:**
>
> How do I? -- ask on English Language & Usage Stack Exchange (tell them what tags to use -- your product tag at minimum)
>
> I got this **error**, why? -- ask on English Language & Usage Stack Exchange
>
> I got this error and I'm sure it's a **bug** -- report it on your own site
>
> I have an idea/request -- report it on your own site
>
> Why do you? -- ask in your own community (support forum, etc)
>
> When will you? -- ask in your own community

...

---

I am not sure if people will associate *errors* and *bugs* with English Language and usage. Just to be clear, ***what type of products are we talking about here?***

I see that a generic template (that came from SO, the root) is used across the SE sites with just a change in the site name. ***Shouldn't this be rephrased to be more in line with the goals of individual sites?***

A rather trivial question but posting it nonetheless.

Comment: I'm not sure it is trivial, and yes, it should be tailored more. Or omitted altogether (which is probably the best thing for ELU).

Comment: Sounds like the text was adapted from Stackoverflow.

Comment: I hadn't seen that this says "EL& U works really well for technical support": besides being untrue, this encourages exactly the questions we are trying to reduce.

Comment: I don't think that section serves any specific purpose for E.L. & U. that "[avoid overt self promotion](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)" doesn't. The only products relevant to this site are dictionaries and grammar textbooks if I am not mistaken, which don't need technical support from us. Yet, it might be a good idea to leave the generic sections up so that when people visit other S.E. subdomains, say perhaps the Ubuntu S.E., they might already be familiar with typical rules, since most of the H.C. topics are rather generic and it seemslike a read one, read 'em all ordeal.

Comment: Hilarious! What is a "product tag" and how does one create it? "Mark's All-Purpose Editing Services, Just $50 an Hour With a One-Hour Minimum. PayPal Accepted!" I'm going to become an Internet billionaire on EL&U! Damn it, @Tonepoet, why did you have to go and cite "avoid overt self promotion"? What is the policy on *covert* self-promotion? :-)

Comment: @MarkHubbard Figured it'd be more along the lines of "Buy a product tag today!"  Regardless,I don't think it's in the help center but I suppose it's the same as it is with anything else that's covert: "It's fine just as long as you don't get caught." It's hard to say if this whole operation isn't just a scam to garner hits and peddle premium subscriptions for M.W. with teasers or if I'm just a shill for Public Domain Inc., isn't it? More seriously, I cited it because there aren't many logical interpretations of supporting a product here. The alternative is we're tech support for the O.E.D. ...

Comment: _"I got this error, why?"_ Comma splice :(

Answer (score 5):

I suggest the page be removed in its entirety. There is no conceivable "product" which would be on-topic on ELU.SE.

Answer (score -1):

Bump, the description is still as it is described in the question.

Comment: It's still as described in the question because moderators can't edit it. That page is only editable by staff. The best way to get it changed is to write an answer here proposing the rewritten text you would like to see (or its removal), and then we can take the community's views expressed by voting figures to TPTB. I'll set the ball rolling...